# Помогите решить 4-ую задачу из Проекта Эйлера

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача звучит так:

- "Число-палиндром с обеих сторон (справа налево и слева направо) читается одинаково. Самое *большое число-палиндром, полученное умножением двух двузначных чисел – 9009 = 91 × 99.*
  *Найдите самый большой палиндром, полученный умножением двух трехзначных чисел."*

```
def up(x, y):
    if y == 999:
        x += 1
        return x, y
    else:
        y += 1
        return x, y
def four(x, y):
    while x != 1000:
        num = str(x*y)
        if num == num[::-1]:
            guess = num
            x, y = up(x, y)
            print(guess)
        else:
            x, y = up(x, y)
    return guess
print(four(100, 100))
```

Выдает ошибку *"local variable 'guess' referenced before assignment"*, хотя если уменьшить передаваемое значение при вызове функции до десяти всё работает как надо.

```
print(four(10, 10)) #вот так вот
```

Я так и не смог понять почему в первом случае работает, а во втором нет.

Comment: Потому что в одном случае заходит в ветку if num == num[::-1]:, а во втором не заходит.

Comment: Какой то непонятный алгоритм. Сегодня, видимо, международный день спагетти-кода...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При вызове `four(100, 100)` функция не находит ни одного кандидата в ответы, а в этой ситуации код не определяет переменную `guess` и возникает ошибка в операторе `return guess`.

Распечатка пар `x * y` показывает что перебираются пары вида `100 * y` и вида `x * 999`:

> ```
> 100 * 100
> 100 * 101
> ...
> 100 * 998
> 100 * 999
> 101 * 999
> 102 * 999
> ...
> 998 * 999
> 999 * 999
> ```

Среди этих пар нет нужной.

Comment: Я в блоке "if y == 999" функции "up()" забыл добавить обнуление y. Я просто добавил "y = 10" перед "return x, y" и все ошибки пропали